# Include static html file with Angular CLI application only in e2e tests

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor, angular-cli

I want to have one specific static (non-Angular) html file that is only built and served when running my e2e tests in an Angular CLI application. In the production application that static file should not be available.

I'm trying to get this to work in a minimal repro, but fail to see how I can do this. I've started by creating an `ng new` (Angular CLI 7.3.9) application with all defaults. I've then done this:

1. Add `"src/production-static-page.html",` to `"assets"` in my `angular.json` file underneath the main `projects` entry.
2. Created that file with just `<p id="foo">bar</p>` as contents.
3. Extended the scaffolded e2e test with this:

   ```
   it('can navigate to e2e-only html', () => {
     browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
     browser.get('/e2e-only-static-page.html');
     const text = element(by.css('#foo')).getText();
     expect(text).toEqual('bar');
     browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
   });
   ```

And that just works, because that html file is just a normal production file, which is thus also available when I deploy my application to production.

I fail to see how I should configure the `"foo-bar-e2e"` project in the `angular.json` file in a way that another html file (let's say `e2e-only-static-page.html`) is only served up for e2e tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. It's not very convenient, as there [seems to be no reuse of configs in angular.json](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10612), but it works.

Steps in `angular.json`:

1. Duplicate the `"build"`section, name it `"build-e2e"`
2. Include your e2e-only asset in that build
3. Duplicate the `"serve"` section, name it `"serve-e2e"`
4. Reconfigure that section to use `"browserTarget": "my-project:build-e2e"`
5. Change `"my-project-e2e"` > `"architect"` > `"e2e"` > `"configurations"` > `"production"` > `"devServerTarget"` to be `"my-project:serve-e2e:production"` (the element you created in steps 3 and 4.
6. Change `"my-project-e2e"` > `"architect"` > `"e2e"` > `"options"` >  `"devServerTarget"` to be `"my-project:serve-e2e"` (the element you created in steps 3 and 4.

And done! Now `ng e2e` has access to that html file, whereas `ng serve` and production builds do not.